# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, sentiment-analysis

I am writing a pytorch sentiment analysis model.
I would like to use my own dataset with torchtext.
https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-sentiment-analysis
I try to modify above repository with torchtext.

```
tokenize = lambda x: x.split()
comment= Field(sequential=True , use_vocab=True, tokenize=tokenize, lower=True)
Label= Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False)
fields={'comment':('c', comment), 'Label':('L', Label)}
mydata = '/content/'
train_data, valid_data, test_data = TabularDataset.splits(
                                                      path=mydata,
                                                      train_data='train.csv',
                                                      valid_data='valid.csv',
                                                      test_data='test.csv',
                                                      format='csv',
                                                      fields = fields)
```

The above code give an error at the last part where it splits the dataset.
And the error is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-cb08939d17bf> in <module>()
      5                                                       test_data='test.csv',
      6                                                       format='csv',
----> 7                                                       fields = fields)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Could you help me understand and solve this problem.

Comment: Your code expected `TabularDataset.splits()` to return a sequence of three values.  But instead it returned an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`torchtext.data.TabularDataset.splits` expects the keyword argument `fields` to be a list of tuples of `(str, torchtext.data.Field)`. You can fix your code by passing a list with appropriate ordering of values of your current `fields` dictionary.